# Create span inside TD with javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, dom, dom-manipulation

I want to add `<span>`s into `<td>`s in javascript using a loop. The reason for me was to be able to grab the text content's width since it will be the same as the span. But now I just want to know...

Working snippet:

```js
function mach()
{
    var span = Div1.appendChild(document.createElement("SPAN"));
    span.setAttribute("id","Div"+1);
    var tex = span.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hola Que Tal Me Gusta"));
    //console.log(tex, tex.length,tex.width);
    var HisWidth = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("Div1")).getPropertyValue('width')
    console.log(HisWidth,Div1);
     
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFE0" text="#000000">
  

<table id="tabelle" style="float:left" cellpadding="12" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
            <td id="Div1"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
            <td id="Div2"></td>
    </tr>
</table>        
  
 <input type="button" onClick="mach()" value="  create span inside td   "> 
  </body>


</html>
```

```js
var array = new Array();
var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
    table.border = '0';
    table.appendChild(tableBody);
  
var x="Hello";
var y = "World";

function makeAndFillTable()
{
    
        array.push(x,y);
        

        var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("Historie");
        

        tableBody.innerHTML = "";
        var j=array.length;
        

    
        for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++,j--)
        {
        
            var tr = document.createElement('TR');
                tableBody.appendChild(tr);
            
            var td = document.createElement('TD')
            td.setAttribute("id","td"+i);
           
            var span = td.appendChild(document.createElement("SPAN"));
            span.setAttribute("id","span"+i);
            
            span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[j-1]));
            var HisWidth = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("span"+i)).getPropertyValue('width')
            console.log(HisWidth,span0);
            

            td.style.cssText='width:251.665px;text-align:right;font-size:14px';

            

            tr.appendChild(td);
            myTableDiv.appendChild(table)
            
            
            
        }
        
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<input type="button"value="there"onClick="makeAndFillTable()">

<div class="Historie" id="Historie">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I get this error:
**Uncaught TypeError: Window.getComputedStyle: Argument 1 is not an object.**

The Problems have to be here:

1. *var span = td.appendChild(document.createElement("SPAN"));*

and

1. *var HisWidth =    getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("span"+i)).getPropertyValue('width')*

In the first snippet, I take the object ID directly, in the second snippet(1.) its just the variable name in the loop.
Im having trouble on how to syntactically correctly loop through the right ID in that line of code,
im giving every span in every loop a different id ***span.setAttribute("id","span"+i);*** But I cant just write "td"+i.appendChild...

I absolutely dont know whats the Problem with the 2. line of code since its exactly the same as in the first snippet

I tried adding

**var tede = new Array();**    outside the function

and change the function to

```
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++,j--)
    {
    
        var tr = document.createElement('TR');
            tableBody.appendChild(tr);
        
        var td = document.createElement('TD')
        td.setAttribute("id","td"+i);
        
        tede[i]=document.getElementById("td"+i);
        var span = tede[i].appendChild(document.createElement("SPAN"));
        span.setAttribute("id","span"+i);
        
        span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[j-1]));
        var HisWidth = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("span"+i)).getPropertyValue('width')
        console.log(HisWidth,span0);
        

        td.style.cssText='width:251.665px;text-align:right;font-size:14px';

        

        tr.appendChild(td);
        myTableDiv.appendChild(table)

    }
```

Along many different things, but this seemed to be a solid approach, yet doesnt work either...:(

After moving **myTableDiv.appendChild(table)** just after  table.border = '0';**strong text**  and moving **tr.appendChild(td);**  just after **tr.appendChild(td);**  I get the computed width "auto" but not the actual width...
console.log(document.getElementById("span"+i).style.width); returns an empty string...

Im open for any help to enlighten my view =)

Comment: You never add anything to the DOM until the end of the function. `getElementById()` finds elements in the DOM which yours are not at that point, thus it returns `null` and `getComputedStyle()` throws the error **Uncaught TypeError: Window.getComputedStyle: Argument 1 is not an object.**. You could change it to `getComputedStyle(span)` to prevent the error, yet there is nothing to compute at that point. To get the actual computed values elements need to be in the DOM.

Comment: OK thanks, so basically I need to fully add it inbetween steps

Answer (score 0):

```
function ausgabe()
{

        array.push(x,y);
        
    
        var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("Historie");
        myTableDiv.appendChild(table)
    
        tableBody.innerHTML = "";
        var j=array.length;

        var i;
        
        for(i=0;i<array.length;i++,j--)
        {
        
    
            var tr = document.createElement('TR');
                tableBody.appendChild(tr);
        
            var td = document.createElement('TD')
            td.setAttribute("id","td"+i);
            tr.appendChild(td);
            
            var span = td.appendChild(document.createElement("SPAN"));
            span.setAttribute("id","span"+i);
            
            span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[j-1]));
            var HisWidth = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("span"+i)).getPropertyValue('width');
            
            td.style.cssText='width:251.665px;text-align:right;font-size:14px';
    
            if (!Number.isInteger(i/2))
            {
                td.style.cssText='width:251.665px;text-align:right;font-size: 22px;font-weight: 550';
            }
            console.log(HisWidth,span0);
            console.log(document.getElementById("span"+i).offsetWidth);
            

        }
        
        

        
}
```

did the job...Thanks Lain, after your point it was just a matter of using the right way to get the width...